# Doctrine query builder native mysql variables

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have the following query which i'm not sure at all how it can be written as doctrine query builder or how should i use it with doctrine.
Can you help me out with it and give a bit of explanation about using native variables.

```
SET @num := 0;
UPDATE question_manager
LEFT JOIN survey_questions
ON t2.question_id = t1.id
SET t1.step = @num := (@num +1)
WHERE t2.survey_id = 31
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more the query you want to make ?
And why don't you use php variables instead of mysql native variables ?

Comment: well .. yeah i could do it from php but i want to learn how to do this type of query using doctrine :

Answer (score 0):

In the end i solved it by doing a foreach in php that does the same thing.

```
$i = 0;

foreach($array as $key) {
 $key[] = $i++;
}
```